# Making SharePoint online REST Call through ADAL and AzureAD

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure, adal

I have integrated an office 365 trial domain into my Azure AD.  In the Azure AD I have created a custom application and given it the client key and client secret.  Now I am trying to authenticate a simple application using the client id and client secret, get the access token and make a REST call to SharePoint Online.  I have given the necessary permissions to the application to make the REST calls.  However when I make the call I get an unauthorized error.  Does anyone know what is going wrong here.  This is the code I am using.

//Code to get the access token through ADAL

```
    AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com", false);
    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(clientID, clientSecret);
    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireToken("https://mytenant.sharepoint.com", clientCred);
```

//Code to make the call

```
     string requestUrl = "https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/TeamSite/_api/Web/Lists";
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestUrl);
     request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/atom+xml"));
     request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) //I get unauthorized here
     {

     }
```